# How to fire a matchstick without matchbox

Tags: home

How to fire a matchstick without matchbox, there use only any chemical or any secret elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire it from another source of fire. It will catch fire by itself and light easily.

If this isn't a possibility, you can try either striking on rough materials(rocks, sandpaper, some walls):
[image: how to matchstick]

Or, you can create a spark that will reach the match. This should do(actually, this is a minimalistic version of fire).

Comment: [Safety matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match#The_safety_match) won't ignite when rubbed on a rough surface.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen men draw their pants leg tight against their skin and then draw the head of the match across the tight fabric, generating heat by friction. The matchhead bursts into flame from the heat.